# Username and password to connect to the C# library on IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, amqp

I'm on a mission to configure and test IBM MQ at my work. With that, I implemented a library in the C# language using [AMQP.Net Lite](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) to connect to IBM MQ and send and receive messages. However, even reading IBM's own tutorials and documentation, I was unable to identify how to create the username and password that I will use when connecting to a library, be it C# or Java. Can you help me with this issue?

In this case, I'm using version 9.2 on a Windows machine and even following this [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-specify-userid-and-password-when-connecting-ibm-mq), I couldn't be successful with it.

When implementing using AMQP.Net Lite, following this [tutorial](https://%20https://azure.github.io/amqpnetlite/articles/hello_amqp.html), for the connection to be made, it is necessary to provide a username and password. The implementation where the username and password are provided is below:

```
Address address = new Address("amqp://username:password@hostname:port");
Connection connection = new Connection(address);
Session session = new Session(connection);
```

Other implementations, including using IBM's own lib, cite an application username and password that must be entered. However, the library I need to implement focuses on AMQP implementation

Comment: When you say you are unable to figure out how to create the username and password - do you mean how to create the fields in your code, or do you literally mean you don't know how to create, on the O/S, the username and password? If the former, can you show the code you have so far, or at least the portion that deals with connecting to the queue manager so we can know what interface, exactly, you are using.

Comment: You can find some sample code [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/dotnet), where this [module](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/blob/master/dotnet/connPropBuilder.cs) deals with the connection properties including userid and password.

Comment: @MoragHughson Hi friend. I am referring to an application user and not an operating system user. In my case, the implementation carried out in AMQP.Net Lite requires a username and password for the connection to be made. I updated the post details for you to understand better.

Comment: @chughts Do you know how these users are created? This part is what I still don't understand how to do.

Comment: IBM MQ does not have its own user repository. By default IBM MQ will authenticate against the OS.  Your other choice is against LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear about which area you are having a problem with other than saying: "how to create username and password".

So, I'm going to go with that you are new to IBM MQ, AMQP and possibly Windows, too. (No offence intended.)

The key comment was JoshMc's comment was: "***IBM MQ does not have its own user repository. By default IBM MQ will authenticate against the OS. Your other choice is against LDAP.***"

What means is that MQ does not do authentication (itself) but farms it off or outsources it to another application (i.e. OS or LDAP).  Therefore, the first thing you need to check is what do you have set for CONNAUTH (queue manager parameter)? The default is 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS', which is the authentication information object for local OS authentication.

So, you could use your own UserId and Password and when your application connects with your credentials, it will ask the OS (i.e. Windows) to perform the authentication. I strongly recommend you not use your own UserId and Password because it is a security risk plus your company may see it as a security risk and fire you. It is far better to create a test-only account.

You are doing everything on your own PC, therefore, you kind of need to be an expert in 3 areas: developer, MQAdmin and SysAdmin.

First, your SysAdmin job, lets start by creating a test-only account on your PC and call it 'mqtester' with a password of 'BlueSky#2023'.

Open a Command Prompt and issue the following command:

```
net user mqtester BlueSky#2023 /add
```

For MQ authorization, it is best to do it by group not individual UserIds. I get to that later, so just create a group called 'mqtest'.

```
net localgroup mqtest /add
```

Now add your new UserId to the new group:

```
net localgroup mqtest mqtester /add
```

MQAdmin job, now assuming you have not changed your default authentication, the queue manager, via Windows, can now authenticate your new UserId and Password.

Next, your MQAdmin job, is to give authorization to the UserId or more specifically, the new group you created.

You need to allow your UserId authorization to connect to the queue manager, this check is done after the authentication. We will do the authorization by group not UserId.

```
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -t qmgr -g mqtest +connect +inq +dsp
```

where {QM_NAME} is the name of your queue manager.

Next, you need to allow your UserId to access the queue to either get or put messages. Let's say your queue is called 'TEST.Q01'. To authorization your new group to access the queue, you need to issue the following command:

```
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -n TEST.Q01 -t queue -g mqtest +allmqi +dsp
```

If you want access to all queues that begin with 'TEST.' then use you a wildcard. And yes it is 2 asterisks (i.e. '**').

```
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -n TEST.** -t queue -g mqtest +allmqi +dsp
```

Finally, as a developer, you should now be able to run your program, connect to the queue manager, have your UserId and Password authenticated and have permission to access the queue manager and the queues you want.

Comment: Hello friend. Thanks a lot for the help! You're right, I'm not experienced in these matters and I took on this task without the necessary knowledge and I'm learning as problems arise. Therefore, I thank you for your patience and attention to what you have taught me so far. The entire process of creating the username and password that you taught was successful. However, now I'm getting an error when connecting to the lib. Basically the error is: "The transport 'TcpTransport' is closed"

Comment: Using IBM MQ Explorer, I enabled remote administration for the Queue Manager, as shown in this image http://prntscr.com/2lV7tykMK84l. Was this also necessary? The connection string I am creating is structured as follows: amqp://username:password@host:port

Comment: No, you did not need remote administration to do your testing but it's nice to have.

Comment: I assumed you had AMQP running in the queue manager. What port are you using? The default port is 5672. Did you follow the instructions here for setting up AMQP in the queue manager: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=server-creating-using-amqp-channels

Comment: Hello friend. AMQP is actually not running on the queue manager, because going to Properties -> Extended I saw that it is not supported: https://prnt.sc/b4C2DD1apg-9

Comment: Well, if you didn't install the AMQP package when you installed the MQ Server then it will always fail.  Restart the MQ installer, and install AMQP, Java and all developer components. I've written a couple programs that use AMQP interface in MQ without issue.

Comment: Hello friend. Thank you for the explanation. After installing AMQP, the connection to AMQP is made successfully using the library I mentioned. However, when I send a message, I am getting a timeout error and I believe it has to do with a "sender-link" that the library asks me to inform. I'm researching to understand what this would be like in IBM MQ and I also saw that some codes with this lib, for example, use /amqp/queue/QUEUE_NAME as the queue name).

Comment: I don't know much about AMQP.Net Lite but this link should help you: https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/blob/master/docs/articles/hello_amqp.md

Answer (score 0):

I think this is boiling down to how to "Create a user and group for running MQ client applications" on a queue manager running on windows.

To create a queue manager on windows you can follow the steps in the
[Get an IBM MQ queue for development on Windows](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-windows/) tutorial. Step 5 of which is "Step 5. Create a user and group for running MQ client applications".